# If $\sup \limits_{x\in M}f(x)<\infty$, $f$ has a global maximum in $M$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$  be a closed, non-empty set and let $f:
>  M\to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that for all
>   $(x_n)_n\subset M$:
>
> If $(f(x_n))_n$ is bounded, then $(x_n)_n$ is bounded aswell.
>   Show that if $\sup \limits_{x\in M}f(x)<\infty$, $f$ has a global
>   maximum in $M$.

**My Idea:**

Since $\sup \limits_{x\in M}f(x)<\infty$, there is a $K\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)\leq K$ and thus $(f(x_n))_n$ with $(x_n)_n\subset M$ is bounded and hence $(x_n)_n$ is bounded aswell. But how can I conclude that there is an $\hat{x}\in M$ such that $f(\hat{x})=\sup \limits_{x\in M}f(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $f(x_n)\to\sup f(x)$.

As the supremum is finite, $(f(x_n))_n$ is bounded, so $(x_n)_n$ is also bounded. By [Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), there is a convergente subsequnece $(x_{n_k})_k$, that is, $x_{n_k}\to x$ and, because $M$ is closed, $x\in M$.

Now, the continuity of $f$ and the fact that $(f(x_n))_n$ is convergent, do the last job:

$$f(x)=f(\lim_k x_{n_k})=\lim_k f(x_{n_k})=\lim_n f(x_n)=\sup f.$$

Comment: Is this statement that if $\{ f(x_n) : n = 1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is bounded then $\{x_n: n=1,2,3,\ldots\}$ being viewed as a statement about the nature of the function $f$? Certainly it is NOT true of continuous functions in general: there are many continuous functions that map unbounded sets to bounded sets.

Comment: Of course, it is an hypothesis of the problem.